# ¿Cómo mostrar una scroll-bar/barra de desplazamiento dejnado el overflow:hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy intentando hacer que la barra de `scroll` se muestre pero que el `overflow` sea `hidden` para que ningún elemento sobresalga de la página porque tengo elementos arrastrables. ¿Se les ocurre alguna forma de hacerlo o no es posible?

Esto es lo que quiero conseguir:

```js
document.getElementById("elemento").addEventListener("mousedown", mover);
   function mover(e){
       elem = e.target;//obtener elemento
      function pocisionar(pageX, pageY){
          elem.style.left = pageX -  elem.offsetHeight/2 + 'px';
          elem.style.top = pageY -  elem.offsetHeight/2 + 'px';
          
      }
      function obtener(event){
           pocisionar(event.pageX, event.pageY);
       }
      elem.addEventListener('mousemove', obtener);
      elem.addEventListener('mouseup', eliminar);
       function eliminar(e){
         elem.removeEventListener('mousemove', obtener);
        }
     }
```

```css
div{
        height: 200px;
        width: 300px;
        background-color: grey;
        overflow:hidden;
        /*overflow:scroll;*/
        position:relative;
    }
 #elemento{
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        position: absolute;
 }
```

```html
<div>
    <p id="elemento">Elemento arastrable</p>
</div>
```

Quiero conservar el `overflow:hidden` para que el elemento no se salga del elemento gris, pero quiero que en todo momento se muestren las baras de desplazamiento, `overflow:scroll`.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si. Siempre en las preguntas se pide poner ejemplos de código propio y/o investigación previa, agrega un [Ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre creando un `<div>` padre que sea como una *'ventana'* que me muestre parte de un `<div>` hijo al que llamare *'background'*, este hijo tendra el tamaño que quiera mientras sea mayor el ancho y el alto que el `<div>` *ventana* (así, dándole overflow:scroll a *ventana* me mostrara siempre los scrolls).
La caja arrastrable *'draggablebox'* a su vez es hijo de la caja *'background'* y se mueve libremente por ella.

Después la dificultad reside en evitar poder mover la caja más allá de los límites del *'background'* y que no quede escondida, al tener un scroll se dificulto hacer los cálculos ya que al hacer scroll a la derecha lo que sucede es que el *'background'* se mueve hacia la izquierda y lo mismo sucede si scrolleo hacia abajo *'background'* se va hacia arriba, por eso es un poco liado el código.

```js
const draggable = document.getElementById('draggable')
const dragablestyle = getComputedStyle(draggable) // estilos css solo lectura
const background = document.getElementById('background')
const bckgrclient = background.getBoundingClientRect() // esto es para obtener la posicion relativa del background con respecto al viewport
const bckgrstyle = getComputedStyle(background)
const windowdiv = document.getElementById('window')
const windowstyle = getComputedStyle(windowdiv)

draggable.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
  e.target.style.cursor = 'pointer'
})

draggable.addEventListener('dragend', (e) => {

  let isLeftCorrect = e.clientX > parseInt(bckgrstyle.left.replace('px','') + 50)
  let isRightCorrect = e.clientX < parseInt(bckgrstyle.left.replace('px','') + 50) + background.offsetWidth - windowdiv.scrollLeft
  let isTopCorrect = e.clientY > parseInt(bckgrstyle.top.replace('px','') + 50)
  let isBottomCorrect = e.clientY < parseInt(bckgrstyle.top.replace('px','') + 50) + background.offsetHeight - windowdiv.scrollTop

  if(isLeftCorrect && isRightCorrect && isTopCorrect && isBottomCorrect){
    draggable.style.left = 
    `${e.clientX - bckgrclient.x - (parseInt(dragablestyle.width.replace('px',''))/2) + windowdiv.scrollLeft}px`
    draggable.style.top = 
    `${e.clientY - bckgrclient.y - (parseInt(dragablestyle.height.replace('px',''))/2) + windowdiv.scrollTop}px`
  } else console.log('No se puede arrastrar... fuera de los limites!')

})
```

```css
#window{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#background{
  position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: rgb(103, 255, 136);
  overflow:hidden;
}

#draggable{
  position: absolute;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: .8;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div id="window">
    <div id="background">
      <div id="draggable" draggable="true">draggable box</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="scripts2.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
</body>
```

Si movemos la caja más allá de los limites no nos dejara hacerlo (colocara la caja en la posición donde estaba al empezar a arrastrar) y mostrara un mensaje de advertencia en la consola.

Puedes ejecutar el código directamente en mi respuesta picando en 'ejecutar' pero no te lo recomiendo porque esta herramienta de StackOverflow no da los mismos resultados que si ejecutaras el HTML en una pestaña nueva, mejor copia y pega el código en tu IDE como harías normalmente y después ejecútalo en tu navegador, a mí me funciona perfecto. Saludos.

Disculpa si no es la solución más practica o corta, seguramente otro podrá darte una mejor respuesta solo acepte el desafío y quería darte mi aporte además de ejercitarme yo mismo.